# Can't log path of uploaded images outside of foreach loop

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I simply want to get download urls from firestorage and push it to empty array.

In handleSubmit I try this but it logs empty array.. if I try it inside it logs correctly

```
 let images = [];
thumbnail.forEach(async (file) => {
  const uploadPath = `property/${user.uid}/${file.name}`;
  const imgRef = ref(storage, uploadPath);
  await uploadBytes(imgRef, file);
  images.push(await getDownloadURL(imgRef));
  console.log(images); //Logs correct array of urls
});

console.log(images);// Logs empty array
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your callbacks are async. The console.log is firing before the callbacks have completed.

To wait for all of the async callbacks to complete before logging use `Promise.all()` with `map` to return the promises and wait for them.

```js
let images = [];
Promise.all(thumbnail.map(async (file) => {
  const uploadPath = `property/${user.uid}/${file.name}`;
  const imgRef = ref(storage, uploadPath);
  await uploadBytes(imgRef, file);
  images.push(await getDownloadURL(imgRef));
  console.log(images);
}).then(() => {
  console.log(images);
});
```

You can improve on this further by returning from the callback and removing the temporary images array

```js
Promise.all(thumbnail.map(async (file) => {
  const uploadPath = `property/${user.uid}/${file.name}`;
  const imgRef = ref(storage, uploadPath);
  await uploadBytes(imgRef, file);
  return await getDownloadURL(imgRef);
}).then((images) => {
  console.log(images);
});
```